# Concretize data type in inherited class

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

Say I we have following example of code. I have interface of DataFiller and 2 implementations of it. Each implementation takes different type of container.

```
    public interface DataFiller {
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2 Object container);
    }

    public class InOrderDataFiller implements DataFiller {
        @Override
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, Object container) {
            if (container instanceof InOrderContainer) {
                container.setContent1(param1);
                container.setContent2(param2);
            }
        }
    }

    public class ReverseDataFiller implements DataFiller {
        @Override
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, Object container) {
            if (container instanceof ReverseContainer) {
                container.setContent1(param2);
                container.setContent2(param1);
            }
        }
    }
```

To be sure I can fill them, I need to check data type of container using instanceof. I wonder, if there is a way, how to have more elegant code of this, say with static type checking. Is there a way, how can I specify data type of container in specific implementation of DataFiller? I would like to have code more like this (of course this will not compile):

```
    public interface DataFiller {
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2 Container container);
    }

    public class InOrderDataFiller implements DataFiller {
        @Override
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, InOrderContainer container) {
            container.setContent1(param1);
            container.setContent2(param2);
        }
    }

    public class ReverseDataFiller implements DataFiller {
        @Override
        public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, ReverseContainer container) {
            container.setContent1(param2);
            container.setContent2(param1);
        }
    }
```

Yes, I can avoid using the interface at all and just use the implementations. The interface should be more like template, how to write more fillers. I thought about using generic type, but I am not sure if it is what I need. Is DataFillerFactory what I need and perform dynamic type checking in it?

Comment: Generics are good here imo.

Comment: Is `Container` a supertype of those containers? Or is there any common super type of them?

Comment: Yes, Container is supertype of both containers. But they may have different structure. Each implementation of filler knows structure of it's related container.

Comment: Should this class really be concerned with what type of `Container` it is working with? I feel like if there is a difference between `Container` classes, it should be up to the `Container` implementations to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Problem is, I cannot touch neither of Container implementations itself, because they are automatically generated and precompiled classes. Say Container itself cannot have any business logic at all, it is just box for data without any functions. How the container should be filled knows it's filler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sotirios already commented, generics would do some good here:

```
public interface DataFiller<T extends Container> {
    void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, T container);
}

public class InOrderDataFiller implements DataFiller<InOrderContainer> {
    @Override
    public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, InOrderContainer container) {
        container.setContent1(param1);
        container.setContent2(param2);
    }
}

public class ReverseDataFiller implements DataFiller<ReverseContainer> {
    @Override
    public void fillContainer(Object param1, Object param2, ReverseContainercontainer container) {
        container.setContent1(param2);
        container.setContent2(param1);
    }
}
```

You could also introduce generics for the parameter types, if they depend on the container type as well.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I thought about, but just was not able to write correct code. :) Thanks!